# Error with smarthost forwarding mail

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011, smarthost

I have just set up a new SBS2011 server, it is using the ISP smarthost to send mail. Normal sending of mail works fine, but one of our users has a blackberry which rather than setting up BES for 1 user, we wanted to forward on any emails to the blackberry email address.

I set up a forwarder through exchange to forward all emails sent to user@company.com to user@blackberry.com and ticked leave a copy in mailbox. Upon testing this we kept getting bouncebacks saying:

antispam3.c0bise7.blackberry rejected your message to the following email addresses:

user@blackberry.com

gave this error

> #5.7.1 your access to submit messages to this email system has been rejected
>   delivery has failed to these recipients or groups: user@blackberry.com

and then i created another send connector for the blackberry address which then came up with this error:

> a problem occurred during the delivery of this message to this email address, try sending this message again.
>   the following organisation rejected your message: mail.btconnect.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to submit messages to the blackberry mx, there is nothing you can do about it. Contact the support function at RIM/blackberry